# How to get reverse DNS to work for multiple IPs and domains on Windows Server EC2 instance?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, email-server, reverse-dns, amazon-route53

I have a EC2 instance setup running hMailServer.  I have a primary IP on the system that I am using for example1.com email.  I would like to also add a second domain example2.com using a different IP address on the same server.

I have added a secondary IP address to the instance, setup elastic IPs for both private IPs and setup MX records and A records on Route 53 to point to the proper IP addresses.  I have also requested the pointers for reverse DNS from Amazon for each domain and IP.

I can send and receive email on both domains.

When I go to MXToolbox to check the SMTP settings for example2.com, it indicates that there is a reverse DNS mismatch and it shows example1.com as the name it is returning for the IP.

I assume this has something to do either with the way that Amazon maps the IPs or how they setup the reverse DNS entries.

How do I set it up so that I can get a reverse DNS match on both IPs / Domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the reverse DNS (PTR) records for your elastic IPs by [filling out this form](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request).  Make sure your A records are correct or they will not create the PTR record.